# 'Dense' object has no attribute 'op'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to make a fully connected model using tensorflow.keras, here is my code

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten

def load_model(input_shape):
  input = Input(shape = input_shape)
  dense_shape = input_shape[0]
  x = Flatten()(input)
  x = Dense(dense_shape, activation='relu')(x)
  x = Dense(dense_shape, activation='relu')(x)
  x = Dense(dense_shape, activation='relu')(x)
  x = Dense(dense_shape, activation='relu')(x)
  x = Dense(dense_shape, activation='relu')(x)
  output = Dense(10, activation='softmax')

  model  = Model(input , output)
  model.summary()
  return model
```

but when I call the model

```py
model = load_model((120,))
```

I have this error

```
'Dense' object has no attribute 'op'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please include the full traceback

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are missing `(x)` after your output layer. Try

```
output = Dense(10 , activation = 'softmax')(x)
```

Comment: Damn, I just made the same mistake.  I think I deleted the (x) when I changed my activation ... and I would NEVER have spotted it.